# Chrome extension/jQuery works on one site but not others? Trying to fire an event on clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I have three different js files for three different sites. Let me preface by saying the manifest does have the proper settings to have these these on the proper sites, and only one function of the extension (the most important one) does not work.

The first, which works, is for pages like these: http://hearthstonetopdeck.com/deck.php?d=1613

```
var decklist = [];
$('.cardname').each(function(i, el) {
    var values = $(this).text().split(' ');
    var count = parseInt(values.shift(), 10);
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        decklist.push(values.join(' '));
    }
});
var data = decklist.join("\r\n");
var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "octet/stream"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());

$(document).ready(function(){
var html = $('#deckname').html() + '';
fileName = $('#deckname').text() + '.txt';
html = html.replace(/<h1>#/, '<h1><a class="download" href="#download">DOWNLOAD</a> - #');
$('#deckname').html(html);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[href="#download"]').click(function(){
      saveData(data, fileName);
   }); 
});
```

Running this in the console will work just as it does with the extension. I have tested all 3 of these js files both using the chrome extension method and pasting in the console. Results are identical.

The second site (http://www.hearthhead.com/deck=300/spell-power-on-a-budget), for which it USED to work, no longer does. I can't seem to remember change any code either, and it should fire identically. The issue here is that, while the download link appears, either the event doesn't fire or it simply doesn't work. Here is the code for site #2:

```
var decklist = [];
$('.deckguide-cards-type li').each(function(i, el) {
    var values = $(this).text().substring(1).split(' ');
        if ($.inArray("x2", values) != "-1") {
        values.pop();
        decklist.push(values.join(' '));
    }
    decklist.push(values.join(' '));
});

var data = decklist.join("\r\n");
var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "octet/stream"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());


$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[href="#download"]').click(function(){
      saveData(data, fileName);
   }); 
});

$(document).ready(function(){
var html = $('.text h1').html() + ' hearthstonedeckdl';
fileName = $('.text h1').text() + '.txt';
html = html.replace(/hearthstonedeckdl/, '- <a class="download" href="#download">DOWNLOAD</a>');
$('.text h1').html(html);
});
```

Firing the function saveData on load DOES work exactly as expected, and a .txt file is downloaded with the proper data. This is the intended function on clicking the download link, and it works in the first example.

This final example has not worked period, but as before, firing on load works, properly. It's simply the link I'm having issues with. The site is here: http://www.hearthpwn.com/decks/46364-d3managements-legend-hunter

The code is below:

```
var decklist = [];
$('.col-name').each(function(i, el) { 
    var values = $(this).text().substring(2).substring(0, $(this).text().length - 10).replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.\s']+/g ,"").split(' ');
    if ($.inArray("", values) != "-1") {
    return;
    } else if ($(this).text().substr($(this).text().length - 3, 1) == "2") {
    decklist.push(values.join(' '));
    decklist.push(values.join(' '));
    } else {
    decklist.push(values.join(' '));
    }
});


var data = decklist.join("\r\n");
var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "octet/stream"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());


$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[href="#download"]').click(function(){
      saveData(data, fileName);
   }); 
});

$(document).ready(function(){
var html = $('.t-deck-title').html() + ' hearthstonedeckdl';
fileName = $('.t-deck-title').text() + '.txt';
html = html.replace(/hearthstonedeckdl/, '</br><a class="download" href="#download">DOWNLOAD</a>');
$('.t-deck-title').html(html);
});
```

I'm fairly new to jQuery, but consulting with a friend of mine that has more experience than me can't seem to find the issue, and it's driving me absolutely mad.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare a click event on an anchor before it is created.

Replace this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[href="#download"]').click(function(){
      saveData(data, fileName);
   }); 
});
```

With this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', 'a[href="#download"]', function(){
      saveData(data, fileName);
   }); 
});
```

Or keep your code and make sure you call this:

```
var html = $('.t-deck-title').html() + ' hearthstonedeckdl';
fileName = $('.t-deck-title').text() + '.txt';
html = html.replace(/hearthstonedeckdl/, '</br><a class="download" href="#download">DOWNLOAD</a>');
$('.t-deck-title').html(html);
```

before attaching the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving jquery another namespace? I noticed on the site you provided does not run jquery which might mean on the other sites it may be conflicting.

try

```
var $jg = jQuery.noConflict();
```

at the top of your document.

Then instead of

```
$('.t-deck-title')
```

try

```
$jg('.t-deck-title')
```

Comment: Tried this. No change.